# ElasticSearch - query documents by term and field priority

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm currently working with elasticsearch and I'm trying to implement a query from the Java backend that will query documents from my index not only by term but by field priority as well. In my index, I have documents that have a term and a field that specifies a type.

```
e.g 
term: "Flu Shot"
type: "procedure"

term: "Fluphenazine"
type: "drug"
```

I created a query that will search by term and the elastic index will return the most relevant results matching that term. The functionality I want to create is to create a query to return results matching that same term but ordered by a priority of the 'type' field. For example when I type "flu" I want to get the documents with type: "procedure" first then after them the ones with the type "drug". Currently, the index returns only documents with type "drugs" due to many drugs that start with "flu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

> The `function_score` allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query. To use `function_score`, the user has to define a query and one or more functions, that compute a new score for each document returned by the query.

Example your data in question (using Elasticsearch server 7.9):

1. Create index, and add documents

   ```
    PUT /example_index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "term": {"type": "text" },
          "type": {"type": "keyword"}
        }
      }
    }

    PUT /_bulk
    {"create": {"_index": "example_index", "_id": 1}}
    {"term": "Flu Shot", "type": "procedure"}
    {"create": {"_index": "example_index", "_id": 2}}
    {"term": "Fluphenazine", "type": "drug"}
    {"create": {"_index": "example_index", "_id": 3}}
    {"term": "Flu Shot2", "type": "procedure"}
    {"create": {"_index": "example_index", "_id": 4}}
    {"term": "Fluphenazine2", "type": "drug"}
   ```
2. Query documents using custom scoring logic

   ```
    GET /example_index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "wildcard": {
              "term": {
                "value": "*flu*"
              }
            }
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "type": "procedure"
                }
              },
              "weight": 2
            },
            {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "type": "drug"
                }
              },
              "weight": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
   ```
3. Results:

   ```
    {
      "took" : 2,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 4,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 2.0,
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "example_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 2.0,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "Flu Shot",
              "type" : "procedure"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "example_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "3",
            "_score" : 2.0,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "Flu Shot2",
              "type" : "procedure"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "example_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "2",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "Fluphenazine",
              "type" : "drug"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "example_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "4",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "Fluphenazine2",
              "type" : "drug"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   ```

You can see the documents with `type` set to `procedure` have a higher score than the documents with `type` set to `drug`. This is because we've assigned different weights to the different `type`s in the `function_score`.

Comment: This seems like a good solution if I'm using function score queries but what about term match queries? Especially ones that depend on a custom analyzer for the term? I've tried to wrap it in a bool/must query. It works for term + a type but what If I want to order two or more types by precedence order?